# Can't figure out to solve this image segmentation problem

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, image-segmentation

My training images are made up of blue channels extracted from the ELAs (Error Level Analysis) of some spliced images and the labels just consist their corresponding ground truth masks.

I've have constructed a simple encoder-decoder CNN given down below to do the segmentation and have also tested it on the cell membrane segmentation task. There it performs well and creates near to ground truth images, so I guess the neural network I created is capable enough.

However, it is not working on the spliced images on CASIA1 + CASIA1GroundTruth dataset. Please help me to fix it, I have spent too many days on it trying different architectures and pre-processing on the images but no luck.

[image]
Input Image

[image]
Ground Truth

[image]
Output/Generated Image

For one, it is claiming such high accuracy (98%) and low losses but the output image is so wrong. It is sort of getting the wanted mask if you look carefully but along with it there are a lot of regions splattered with white. Seems like it is not able to get the difference in the intensities of the pixels for the wanted region vs the background. Please help me fix it :(

#### Preparation

```py
def process(img):
    img=img.getchannel('B')
    return img

for i in splicedIMG:
  img=process(Image.open('ELAs/'+str(i)))
  X.append(np.array(img)/np.max(img))

for i in splicedGT:
  lbl=Image.open('SGTResized/'+str(i))
  Y.append(np.array(lbl)/np.max(lbl))

X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)

X = X.reshape(-1, 256,256, 1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 256,256, 1)

X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2)
```

#### Segmenter Model

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (256,256,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (256,256,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1, kernel_size = (1,1), activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

#### Training

```py
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.0001), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('segmenter_weights.h5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data = (X_val, Y_val), batch_size=4, epochs=200, verbose=1, callbacks=[PlotLossesCallback(),model_checkpoint])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I did a stupid one. In order to see what I have picked up for testing from the X array, I multiplied that array by 255 cause PIL doesn't display arrays in 0-1 range. Mistakenly, I just used the same modified variable and passed it in test/prediction.

Comment: If your question is caused by an obvious error, it is unlikely to be useful to future visitors. Why not just delete it?

Comment: Okay. Although as per my experience, it's very rare to get support in machine learning stuff on this site. Probably because one would need to get the dataset, process it and run the training by themselves rather than just quickly checking out a code snippet.